# Javascript: resize the width of an image, mantain proportions but cut the height if needed

Tags: css, image, border

So I want to maintain proportions of an image but as said in the title, I'd like to crop the height to maintain a 16:9 ratio. Currently I'm setting the image as the background and it works, but I get a weird border (EDIT: the border was fixed, check this post, below, for the solution). You can see it in the followin screenshot:

[image]

I'm using an image element because it's easier for the user to move it around in the content editable (if I use a div the user can't select it and move it around freely).

This is the code I'm using:

```
  // I get my editor width and calculate the height
  const imgWidth = parseInt(editor.offsetWidth);
  const imgHeight = imgWidth * 480 / 640;

  const img = document.createElement('img');

  // this class contains background-size: cover
  // I tried also to set border-image-widht: 0 with no luck
  img.classList.add('image');

  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image.webformatURL + ')';
  img.style.width = imgWidth + 'px';
  img.style.height = imgHeight + 'px';
  img.style.maxWidth = imgWidth + 'px';
  img.style.maxHeight = imgHeight + 'px';
```

What would be a better way to resize the image cropping the excess height?
Why there is a little white/grey border when using the image as background?

**EDIT**: it looks like the border is visible if the src attribute is empty, the solution would be to use an transparent png to prevent the border from appearing. Is there a better solution? For now I just added a base64 1x1 pixel transparent image to src and it works:

```
img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII='
```

Comment: Under what conditions is the height "too high?"

Comment: Some pictures are not 16:9. They are for example 300x900. In that case I want to resize the width to match the width of the editor, but crop out the excessive height and mantain the ratio.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure but I think what you're looking for is `object-fit`, set `src` attribute and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit   The border appears because you're not setting a src attribute.

Comment: Wow yes, that fixed the issue. Thanks.